# How to make a UIImageView display full screen (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell. When the image is tapped I want the image to display full screen and then when tapped again, to return to it's normal size. Do I need to create a new view for this? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create new view to show image in full screen.
First get frame of tapped image view with respect to `self.view`, then assign that frame to new view in which you have full imageView. Now with animation, show full image view, and again with tap back to its original frame with animation.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest if you create a new view. It's also easiest if you have a view controller with the table view as a subviews of the main view. Then you can create the new view as a sibling to the table, displayed over the top of the cell, and animate it's frame to full screen.

Comment: I have a view controller with a table view. How would i create a new view on top of this cell? What do you mean by this exactly? Thanks